# Empty window from class

Tags: class, tkinter

Why is the window empty? Do I need to use frame? I'm trying to create a frame out of class and put the information in it.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

#User Interface Code
root = Tk() # Creates the window
root.title("Quiz Game")

class userInfo:
    def __init__(self, user):
        message_label1 = Label(text="I'm going to test your knowledge.", 
        font = ("Arial", "25"), padx=40, pady=20)
        nameLabel = Label(root, text="Enter name", font=("Arial", "15"))
        nameEntry = Entry(root)

        message_label1.pack()
        nameLabel.pack()
        nameEntry.pack()

        self.printButton = Button(root, text="Hello", 
        command=self.printMessage)
        self.printButton.pack()

    def printMessage(self):
        print("Hello")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Main problem is you never call the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is the window empty?

Because you never call the class in your code.
You can solve this by adding a call to the class just above the mainloop.

His you code that works. I also removed the argument "user" from your class because you do not use it anywhere.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

#User Interface Code
root = Tk() # Creates the window
root.title("Quiz Game")

class userInfo:
    def __init__(self):
        message_label1 = Label(text="I'm going to test your knowledge.", font = ("Arial", "25"), padx=40, pady=20)
        nameLabel = Label(root, text="Enter name", font=("Arial", "15"))
        nameEntry = Entry(root)

        message_label1.pack()
        nameLabel.pack()
        nameEntry.pack()

        self.printButton = Button(root, text="Hello", 
        command=self.printMessage)
        self.printButton.pack()

    def printMessage(self):
        print("Hello")

userInfo()
root.mainloop()
```

That said if you are going to use a class it might be better to just inherit from `Tk()` instead of using a basic class.

Here is a class version of your code that inherits from `Tk()`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class UserInfo(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("Quiz Game")
        tk.Label(self, text="I'm going to test your knowledge.", font = ("Arial", "25"), padx=40, pady=20).pack()
        tk.Label(self, text="Enter name", font=("Arial", "15")).pack()
        self.name_entry = tk.Entry(self)

        self.name_entry.pack()

        tk.Button(self, text="Hello", command=self.print_message).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Hello", command=self.new_window).pack()

    def print_message(self):
        print("Hello")

    def new_window(self):
        top = tk.Toplevel(self)
        tk.Label(top, text="Some new window").pack()

UserInfo().mainloop()
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. However, if I were to use the inheritance of Tk(), this means that Toplevel() wouldn't exist, am I correct?

Comment: @Kevin no. You can still use a toplevel.

Comment: How would I need to define 'Toplevel()' if I create a new window from the final code you written above?

Comment: @Kevin simply use the method `Toplevel()`. In my code you can do something like `top = tk.Toplevel(self)` to create a new top level window from within the class. You can even create a class that inherits from `Toplevel()`.

Comment: In the new window that is created using top = tk.Toplevel(self), how would you bring that into my new window function 'def new_window():' because 'self' would not be defined in that window.

Comment: @Kevin I added a top level method to my class on the 2nd example. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Hey, Mike. Within that def new_window(self) functions, I have created another function called def questions(). I want to create a text and display on screen, I would need to use tk.Label(text="blah blah").pack()?

Comment: Hey Mike I am having a lot of trouble. I have created three buttons referring to a question and I want the user to click one button and the program tell if the button they clicked was the correct answer.

Comment: @Kevin It is better to ask a new question about the new problem.